# JQuery draggable on li

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create something like the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/1/) but having a few issues.  I am trying to do my version within a section, whereby it sits alongside something else.  At the moment I have this

```
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" id="portfolio-left">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6" id="portfolio-right">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>
                <li style="background-color: #F00"></li>
                <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
                <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So the slider part is only inside of `portfolio-right`, which takes up 50% of the screeen and `100vh`.  I have set up another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/463/) which demonstrates my problem.  So the grey area is `portfolio-left` which I need untouched.  The right side I need the slides to be `100%` width.  At the moment it is set to `400px` and it displays inline.  As soon as I set it to `100%` the second and third panels drop underneath the first, instead of beside it.

Additionally the slider does not seem to work for me.  Is there any way I can get this functioning properly in the setup I have?

Many thanks

Comment: Your fiddle is loading 2 different jQuery versions. Which do you wish to use?

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/x4k5qk1w/2/ If each `li` is trying to be 100% of it's container, then the container needs a width. If `#slider` is set to 100%, it then `#portfolia-right` needs to have some width defined to it. You can't assign 100% to each item and expect them to render further to the right. If you want it to be dynamic, then `#portfolio-left` needs to be some value either a count or a percentage. For example, 75% and 25%. If the right has to be 100%, what is it being 100% of?

Comment: If I set to 100% it falls under again. This is based on bootstrap, so #portfolio-right is 50%.  This means that slider should be 100% of this 50%, but it doesnt seem to work without making the li drop underneath

Comment: seems to work if I set the li to 33.3%.  Why is this?  Thanks